# Creating a list of players

Tags: list, erlang

I want to create a list of "players".

The user of the program can say how many players he wants.

```
Amount = io:get_line("how many players? \n"),
Int = string:to_integer(Amount),
List = Lists:seq(1,Int).
```

But now I want to create a list of players in the form [Player1, Player2...PlayerN].

Can someone tell me how to do so?

Comment: Come on bob, if you evaluate string:to_integer(Amount) in your Erlang shell you can see it does not return an integer, it returns a tuple, the first element of which is the integer you want. You should pattern match to get the actual integer into Int. Then, 'Lists' is not a valid module, Erlang will treat this as a variable, so you should find the correct module name, which is slightly different, and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that [`string:to_int/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#to_integer-1) will return a tuple, not a single value. Also keep in mind that users do some pretty wild stuff in input, so you'll want to check that. (That said... when you're just trying to get a program written for yourself to test an idea, meh, whatever.)

```
{PlayerCount, _} = string:to_integer(io:get_line("How many players? ")),
```

Pretty simple. Mess around with this a bit. Input is its own world, and its good to think through this stuff a few times in toy programs (and give yourself insane input to see how the program reacts).

From here you can do a few things. If you just want a list of tuples that indicate you have a player whose serial number is a number, that's easy with a list comprehension:

```
Players = [{player, Number} || Number <- lists:seq(1, PlayerCount)],
```

You can write that as a map as well:

```
Players = lists:map(fun(N) -> {player, N} end, lists:seq(1, PlayerCount)),
```

I find the list comprehension more readable, though. Another alternative is to write your own custom recursive function. You *almost never* need to do this, but if you're new to programming it is good practice, and early on its way more readable because you see exactly what is happening each iteration:

```
player_list(Count) -> player_list(1, Count, []).

player_list(Max, Max, Players) ->
    lists:reverse(Players);
player_list(Current, Max, Players) ->
    player_list(Current + 1, Max, [make_new_player(Current) | Players]).
```

Note that the above is equivalent to, but more naturally stated than:

```
player_list(Current, Max, Players) ->
    Next = Current + 1,
    case Next == Max of
        true  -> lists:reverse(Players);
        false -> player_list(Next, Max, [make_new_player(Current) | Players])
    end.
```

Matching in function heads is *much* more clear and readable over the course of a program than a bunch of `case` and `if` statements. Over time, though, as I mentioned above, you will eventually stop writing recursive functions yourself (for the most part) and find yourself using a *lot* of list operations (map, fold, filter, list comprehensions, etc.) as you gain experience.

The details of `make_new_player/0,1` are entirely up to you, of course -- you didn't indicate what sort of structure you wanted for their data, but you can do whatever you want there. Here are some other ways that might play out:

```
[make_new_player(Z) || Z <- lists:seq(1, PlayerCount)]
```

or

```
[#player{serial = Z} || Z <- lists:seq(1, PlayerCount)]
```